# No se actualizan mis estilos Bootstrap al utilizar React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap

Al estar aplicando mis estilos con Bootstrap no se reflejan en la pagina web que esta corriendo en mi servidor local, solo se aplican si reinicio el servidor, pero eso como tal no es muy recomendable porque no puede ver el progreso en tiempo real de los cambios. (No se exactamente que guías agregar para que pudieran apoyarme, solo agrego algunas imágenes, en la que se aplica el mt-5 si se refleja porque es el que tenía al momento de correr el servidor pero al cambiar el valor de mt-20 ya no se refleja, para eso tendría que volver a reiniciar el servidor. ) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

La propiedad MT de bootstrap es **Margin-Top** y solo acepta valores del **0 al 5**, por lo que mt-20 es una sintaxis incorrecta, por eso crees que no se actualizan tus estilos.

Una solución provisional sería de esta forma:

```
<div className='btn-group' style='margin-top:20px;'>
```

Te dejo un enlace para que hagas la prueba tu mismo: [Boostrap v4 Mt- property](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_util_mt-responsive&stacked=h)

Comment: En lugar de agregar esa informacion a la respuesta, deja un comentario al usuario enseñandole a utilizar el sitio. La respuesta solo tiene que ser respuesta...

Comment: Ha sido de mucha ayuda este comentario. Gracias. He estado estudiando esta tecnología, gracias.